# Return distance between two points and assign it to data attribute on location list

Tags: javascript, wordpress, multisite

I am currently working within a Wordpress multisite network. Each website is a location with various ACF option fields related to name, address, phone number and so on. We are looping through the network and outputting all of the locations in state order. We have a search feature that is pulling the locations within the radius searched. This is all working but we need to be able to output the distance and also sort by distance. Currently it is just sorting by alphabetical only. I can not get the distance to output in the data-is-close attribute.

I have tried adding the following:

```
if (d <= 80.4672) {
   status = true;
   //Here is my attribute
   $('.location-state').attr('data-is-close', d);
   }else{}
   return status;
    }
```

The problem is it just adds just the same distance variable to each li element.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Get lat and lon from an address
function advancedSearch() {
var closeCounter = false;
var usrInput = document.getElementById("advanced-search").value;
var apiURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+usrInput+'&key=xxxxx';
$.get(apiURL,function(data){
if (data.results[0] != null) {
var inLat = data.results[0].geometry['location'].lat;
var inLng = data.results[0].geometry['location'].lng;
// console.log(inLat);
// console.log(inLng);
// calcCrow(inLat,inLng,59.3225525,13.4619422);
var matches = document.getElementsByClassName("location-state");
for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
var locLat = matches.item(i).dataset['lat'];
var locLon= matches.item(i).dataset['lon'];
var isClose = calcCrow(inLat,inLng,locLat,locLon);

if (isClose == false) {
matches.item(i).style.display = "none";
}else{
matches.item(i).style.display = "block";
closeCounter = true;
}
}

// console.log(matches);
if (closeCounter == false) {
document.getElementById('no_results').style.display = "block";
}else{
document.getElementById('no_results').style.display = "none";

}
}else{
alert("The address entered was not found, try using your city name instead.");
}
},'json');
}

//This function takes in latitude and longitude of two location and returns the distance between them as the crow flies (in Miles)
//Potential Error MArgin 3.99999 KM or 2.48548 Miles
function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
{
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
var d = R * c;
console.log(d);
//console.log(d*0.621371)
var status = false;
if (d <= 80.4672) {
status = true;
//Here is my attribute
$('.location-state').attr('data-is-close', d);
}else{}
return status;
}

// Converts numeric degrees to radians
function toRad(Value)
{
return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
</script>
<div class="container p-0">
<ul class="subsites">
<?php
foreach ($loc_data as $key => $value) {
$phone_temp = $loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_phone'];
echo '<li id="maplocationsectionbottom-marker-'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_ab_state'].''.$counter++.'" data-lat="'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_lat'].'" data-lon="'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_lon'].'" data-is-close="" class="bi-'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_id'].' location-state location-state-'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_ab_state'].' locationcols">';
echo '<span class="h4 nomargin">'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_name'].' '.$stat.'</span>';
echo '<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">';
echo '<div class="business-data">';
echo '<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">';
echo '<div class="address nomargin">'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_details'].'<span itemprop="streetAddress">'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_address'].'</span><br><span itemprop="addressLocality">'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_city'].'</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_ab_state'].'</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_zip'].'</span></div>';
echo '<p class="nomargin loc-phone"><span itemprop="telephone">'.$phone_temp.'</span></p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_url'].'" class="btn btn-primary with-arrow">View Location <span class="icon-arrow"></span></a>';
echo '</li>';
array_push($active_states,$loc_data[$key][$key2]['loc_ab_state']);
}
}
?>


</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Dumping a ton of unstructured code is not very inviting ;)

Comment: I can not get the distance to output to each li element. I can get it to return the first value but it adds that value to each. See here: if (d <= 80.4672) {
status = true;
//Here is my attribute
$('.location-state').attr('data-is-close', d);
}else{}
return status;
}

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: I updated the question based on your feedback. This is a JS problem as I can not get the distance variable to be added to each li element. It is just adding the same variable to all of them.